# Preview CR2 (raw photo format) in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, photos, file-format, camera-raw

How can I get thumbnails for Canon RAW (*.CR2) photos in Windows XP's Explorer?

Do I have to install a codec, and if so, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hands down, it's got to be IrfanView. It's freeware and can handle most image types with the installation of additional plugins:

Get the app here: http://www.irfanview.com

..and the plugins here: http://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm

One thing to note, from the readme:

> CRW - (version 4.22): allows IrfanView to read Canon CRW/CR2 files
>   (high resolution image version) Note: this PlugIn requires additional
>   Canon DLLs. You can download these DLLs with the Canon ZoomBrowser
>   program:
>
> http://www.canon.com/ or try here:
>   http://irfanview.tuwien.ac.at/plugins/canon_crw.zip

Comment: Tried this already. I can open the images, but I still don't have preview thumbnails in Explorer. This may be some other issue, as I don't have thumbnails for `.png` ang `.jpg` either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, is this any good? http://www.suodenjoki.dk/us/productions/articles/raw_thumbnail.htm

Comment: `crw_thumbnailer.zip` download link does not work anymore.

Comment: This is going well :) I've Googled for the file and came up with this: http://www.woolridge.ca/dpc/ - and obviously the usual recommendations hold true if you're going to take a look at the zip: scan the zip file with anti virus before opening.

Comment: I have been looking for mirrors as well, but without suceess. Your link does not work either.

Comment: I'm thinking that's probably the end of that investigation then. You may want to see if any of the contact details for the author of that site are still valid and see if they have a copy kicking around?

Answer (score 0):

Several years ago, Microsoft published a [RAW thumbnailer and viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8802) specifically for XP that installs a shell extension inside Explorer for providing thumbnails of RAW files. Reading the description posted on the site, it appears to work for both Canon's and Nikon's RAW file formats.